# ¿Cómo puedo llamar un método dentro de un botón en React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando hago clic en el botón Cámara, se puede llamar al método cameraBike, lo he intentado de esta manera pero obtengo un error de que la llamada al método se está utilizando incorrectamente.

```
import React,{useEffect, useRef,useState} from 'react'
import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import {Camera} from 'expo-camera'
import {Text, View } from "react-native";

const BiciRegister = () =>{
    const [startCamera, setStartCamera] = useState(false)
    const stCamera = async () =>{
        const {status} = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()
        if (status === 'granted') {
          // start the camera
          setStartCamera(true)
        } else {
          Alert.alert('Access denied')
        }
    }
    return(
        <View>
            <Button color="#75941B" mode="contained" onPress={cameraBike}>
                Camara
            </Button>
        </View>
    )         
}

const cameraBike = () =>{
        
    return(
        <Camera style={{flex: 1,width:"100%"}}></Camera>
    )
}

export default  BiciRegister
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla. También nos sería de mucha ayuda si agregas el error que recibes. Recuerda hacerlo en forma de texto y no una captura de pantalla

Answer (score 0):

La función cameraBike no está en el scope de la función biciRegister, puedes meter la función cameraBike dentro de biciRegister.

- Pero creo que lo que quieres hacer es mostrar el componente Camera al pulsar el botón Camara, para ello puedes utilizar el renderizado condicional:

```
//añade
const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false);
...
...
return(
        <View>
            {(showCamera === false)?(<Button color="#75941B" mode="contained" onPress={setShowCamera(true)}>
                Camara
            </Button>):
(<Camera style={{flex: 1,width:"100%"}}></Camera>)  )}
        </View>
    )
```